# How to make @depends works with ZF2 AbstractHttpControllerTestCase

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I'm having trouble passing a variable from one test unit to another, through dependency. Here is my test controller:

```
<?php

namespace SyncTest\Controller;

use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;
use PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException;

class TestControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    public function testA()
    {
        $id = 11;
        $this->assertEquals($id, 11);
        return $id;
    }

    /*
     * @depends testA
     */
    public function testB($id)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($id, 11);
    }

}
```

When I run phpunit, it gives the following error:

```
1) SyncTest\Controller\ImageControllerTest::testB
Missing argument 1 for SyncTest\Controller\ImageControllerTest::testB()
```

Any clue about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/*
  * @depends testA
  */`

is not a valid annotation. You have to use

`/**
  * @depends testA
  */`

otherwise PHP's Reflection API does not recognize it and in turn does not expose it to PHPUnit.